# Is there any difference between compressible fluid with Boussinesq approx is and incompressible fluid with the Boussinesq approx?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, approximations

My question is: when I use the [Boussinesq approx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boussinesq_approximation) for a compressible fluid, continuity just gives divergence equal to zero. In the momentum, density disappears everywhere except for the gravity term. The diffusive term can now be simplified using divU=0 in the same way it is done for the incompressible fluid. So to me the governing equations for compressible fluid with Boussinesq approx is and incompressible fluid with the Boussinesq approx are mathematically the same, at least if we don't have temperature changes. In case temperature changes and we solve also for the energy equation, is there any mathematical difference in the equation (I am not much familiar with the energy equation). There is a similar question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/468854/) but not exactly the same, it does not speak about the different terms and difference between constant temperature and varying temperature, and there is not a really good answer there.